# MySQL - Making two or more columns together unique

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a database (MySQL) which will store information on Magic: The Gathering cards.

At the moment, I have the card `names` as `unique`, however I've realized just now that this is an issue with many cards being available across multiple editions, example:

[image]

I am also storing the edition that the card belongs to (as an ID that links to an `editions` table).

Is it possible to define the *combination* of the two columns `name` and `edition` unique rather than just `name`, so that I don't have issues when trying to insert both the above cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create compound unique indexes:

```
UNIQUE KEY `names_editions` (`name`,`edition`)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
UNIQUE KEY column_Name (column1,column2)
```